# How do I remove this unwanted space which seems to be background repeating HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this issue I'm having regarding my gradient background repeating after the page has so much information on.

You can find the page @ http://joshscottonthe.net/AboutMe/ and if you scroll to the bottom you'll see there's a large amount of blank space, ideally I want to half that space at the bottom. I've noticed that when I go into chrome dev tools to inspect the code on that page there's an extra line of code which I've not added and can't find anything in any of my files both HTML and CSS. This code is the line

`<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 1793px;"></div>`

Both this line of code and the repeated background doesn't show on any of the other pages even if I add more content to the page to make the page longer so I'm assuming it has something to do with my "content" div which is responsible for the white box which holds the text on the "About Me" page.

```
/*Main content area with text boxes - Used For About & Assignment Pages 
content {
position: absolute;
width: 50vw;
height: 125vh;
left:0;
right:0;
top: 25vw;
border-radius: 2vw;
margin-bottom: 1vw;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Any thoughts & feedback would be greatly appreciated,

Many thanks,
Josh

Comment: You might want to re-think that design, as currently your site is not mobile responsive, and so will not perform well in Google search results for those using mobiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **.abouth1, .abouth2, abouth3** section of the page remove **height: 100%;**.

Set **#content** to **height: 100%;**

or

Set **#content** to **height: 90%;** to get it closer

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 100%;` in the `.abouth1, .abouth2 and abouth3` and update `#content` height to `100%`;